# Vue-Multiselect looks like zero width text input and has no styling

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how to set up Vue-multiselect component on Laravel 5. Until now i've got a component called register.vue 
and here is the part of the code where i need the component (I won't put all the code here becase it'd be too large.

```
<b-row align-v="center">
    <multiselect
         v-model="selected"
         :options="options">
    </multiselect>
</b-row>
```

Here's where i included the component in the script section

```
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';

   export default {
    components: { Multiselect },
    data(){
        return {
            selected: null,
            options: ['list', 'of', 'options'],
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, what i'm obtaining is a weird component like this one

[This is how it looks when the focus is not in the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kjHa.png)

And when the focus is in the component it only shows an input field with some bullet list which the elemtents of the array with the options are.

Does somebody know what is going on in my app? I've been a lot of time checking if there's some missed css file or stuff like that but everything seems to be OK, except that part, my component seems not be loading any style.

Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you included the b-row part which lets me know you have Bootstrap Vue, considering you have that whole library and all of it's CSS included (it may even contain a multiselect component of its own or use select2). It's most likely that the two stylesheets are messing with each other or one is causing the other not to init correctly or at the proper time.

I found this issue here which seems possibly like it could help you withchecking your styling. https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/718

Also I would get rid of all the other Vue components off that page for a minute and load in Vue Multiselect by itself exactly according to their documentation. That will let you narrow it down to the problem being a conflict between another Vue component or Laravel / when you are starting up Vue multiselect.

I use it in a PHP / Vue project currently this is my working setup with Buefy framework.

I made my own Vue component as a wrapper for multiselect which lets me scope the CSS to just its specific HTML.

```
 <template>
  <multiselect
    v-model="value"
    :options="options"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    label="label"
    track-by="value"
    @input="inputChanged" />
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';

export default {
    components: { Multiselect },
    props: {
        options: {
            type: [Array],
            default() {
                return [];
            }
        },

        savedValue: {
            type: [Array],
            default() {
                return [];
            }
        },

        placeholder: {
            type: [String],
            default: 'Select Option...'
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            value: null
        };
    },

    mounted() {
        this.value = this.savedValue;
    },

    methods: {
        inputChanged(selected) {
            this.$emit('selected', selected.value);
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
@import '../../../../../node_modules/vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css';
</style>
```

Then you can call the component from another file kind of like this.

```
<select-input
:saved-value="artistSelected"
:options="artistOptions"
:placeholder="'Choose an existing artist...'"
@selected="artistChanged"
/>
```

Scoping the CSS like I did will help other things from not messing with your styling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because of the wrong component import statement.

In my case, the following statement gave the correct behaviour:

```
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect/src/Multiselect'
```